# Lack of a ground wire on a ceiling fan installation

Tags: wiring

I am replacing a ceiling fan in my bed room that has been there almost 30 years. The old fan has no ground wire, and there is no wire to connect a ground wire to. Should I just connect the ground wire to the outlet box, or cap off the ground wire?

Comment: Is the box metal or plastic?

Comment: In old days they did not believe that a ceiling fan needed grounding, since nobody would touch it anyway.

Comment: How many wires come into the box? If there is a bare copper wire screwed to the box, and the box is metal, then the fan is effectively grounded by metal screws holding it into the box, and the bare end of the green wire from the fan can be wrapped around the grounded screw for insurance. If there are only *two* wires entering the box, it's **not grounded**. (This assumes neither BX nor conduit was used.)

Comment: you do not need to ground a ceiling fan

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the box please?